# How to use function in subquery

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have one table named MemberCheque where the fields are:

```
MemberName, Amount
```

I want to to show the name and the respective amount in numbers and as well as in words after separating the integer amount from the decimal. So my query is like:

```
 SELECT MemName, Amount, (SELECT (Amount)%1*100 AS lefAmn, dbo.fnNumberToWords(lefAmn)+     

'Hundred ', (Amount) - (Amount)%1 AS righAmnt,  dbo.fnNumberToWords (righAmnt)+' Cents'     

from MemberCheque) AS AmountInWords FROM MemberCheque
```

but my store procedure can take only integer value to change into words. So, I am doing separating the Amount into two parts before and after decimal but when I am trying to run this query it gives me error that lefAmn and righAmnt is not recognised. Because I am trying to send the parameter from the same query.

Comment: You say `but my store procedure can take only integer value to change into words`, but do you mean your function?  What does your function look like?  What is the data type for `Amount`?  If not an integer, then just update your function to accept the appropriate data type; otherwise just cast the values as an integer. Also, saying "This is really so urgent" is just going to annoy people.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Actually the Amount is a Money type as the Amount can be like 234.20. So my Function can take the integer in parameters and then return the Word amount. That is why I am changing the Amount before decimal and after the decimal.

Comment: What database engine are you using? (MySQL, Postgres, MS SQL Server, Oracle...) The behaviour and abilities of stored procedures and/or functions varies widely between platforms.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't alter your function, then CAST the left/right values as INT:

```
CAST((Amount)%1*100 AS INT) AS lefAmn
CAST((Amount) - (Amount)%1 AS INT) AS righAmnt
```

You can't pass the alias created in the same statement as your function parameter, you need:

```
dbo.fnNumberToWords (CAST((Amount)%1*100 AS INT))
dbo.fnNumberToWords (CAST((Amount) - (Amount)%1 AS INT))
```

Comment: Thanks goat..yes I can cast but then how can I send the lefAmn or righAmnt in parameter from the same query? because I need to bind this query with a dataset and display into the crystal report. That is why I want this output from one single query. Can you please suggest me how I can do that?

Comment: Misread the problem initially. You can't pass alias that you just created in the same statement, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a million bro...u really made my day...thanks a lot..its working :)

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that you have a subquery that is returning more than one value, and that is not allowed for a subquery in the `select` clause.

That answer to your specific question is to use `cast()` (or `convert()`) to make the numbers integers:

```
select leftAmt, rightAmt,
       (dbo.fnNumberToWords(cast(leftAmt as int))+'Hundred ' +
        dbo.fnNumberToWords(cast(rightAmt as int))+' Cents'
       ) as AmountInWords
from (SELECT (Amount%1)*100 AS leftAmt,
             (Amount) - (Amount)%1 AS rightAmt
      from MemberCheque
     ) mc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro...this query also working like a charm..u guys just saved my life...cheers :)